# JavaScript regex to capture an < in an XML attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an XML-based scripting language where I want to use something like `<example if="x<5" />`

The `<` is an illegal character for attributes, so XML parsers throw errors.

I still like to use it without escaping, it's nicer for humans to read and write `x<=5`than `x&lt;=5`.

So I'd like to pre-process the XML before it's being parsed and replace the invalid `<`with `&lt;`

But I can't figure out a regex. I've been trying for two hours now.

I've come as far `="(.*?)"` to match everything in an attribute, but I just want that damn `<` and `="(<)"`doesn't do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/576139

Comment: maybe you should use a more advanced xml editor, which doesn't require you to edit a text level.

Comment: I don't know the entire structure of your text, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ht8xP/) works for your provided example. Warning: This might not completely work since regex is not suitable to parse XML.

Comment: @Chris I don't want to parse arbitrary HTML.

Comment: @user3195878 HTML ~= XML. Same thing in this case. You're trying to parse a non-regular language with a regular expression.

Comment: @Chris Aren't regexes almost always used to parse non-regular languages, like human language? Basically I just need to replace a < when it's not starting a tag. I've limited it to a < between =" and ". That should rule out tags. If I catch a couple of < anywhere else, fine, they must be escaped anyway.

Comment: @user3195878 no... you're confusing matching with parsing. Matching, yes. Parsing absolutely not. And your criteria of "not a starting tag" requires parsing.

Comment: @Chris It's a matter of pragmatism to me. The XML subset is tightly controlled, the XML-files are controlled and just a bunch of 'em. If every once in a while the regex matches a tag opening < and the parser produces an error, I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

So first, the obligatory link telling you not to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505154

With that out of the way, here is how you can do what you are trying to do..

You can use a function for the replacement with the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method for String objects, so I would start by matching attributes using your current regex, and then replacing each `<` within each match.  For example:

```
function escapeLtGt(str) {
    return str.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
}

function escapeLtGtInXmlAttrs(str) {
    return str.replace(/="(.*?)"/g, escapeLtGt);
}

// example, logs '<example if="x&lt;5" />'
console.log(escapeLtGtInXmlAttrs('<example if="x<5" />'));
```

Comment: Thanks. That was my solution too. I thought there'd be a way to get just the '<', but apparently there isn't.